# Prevent user email validation message showing twice In craft panel

Tags: craft3, emails, validation, yii

When i enter same email which is already exist and click on save it is showing twice message. Can you please tell me it is craft cms's behavior?
I have checked by disable custom modules and also disable plugin but it still happened. I am using craft cms 3.7 version.
[image]

Comment: Howdy, can you please update this question with more info? I'm assuming the field in the screenshot is not a part of Craft CMS itself, but rather that you're trying to use a plugin from the store or build your own plugin. If you could please provide a bit more context that would be helpful... Thanks!

Comment: Is this in the context of a custom plugin/module you're building?

Comment: Well might as well triple mod this one. Please edit the question to include:
....
- Which Version of Craft 3 (look under Utilities)
- Whether this is in the user creation menu in the CP
- Whether this is a field you wrote as part of a custom CP module
- Whether this is on the site's frontend 
.....
My first recommendation would be to update Craft, and then if these are custom written check if you're outputting two type of error messages when you only needed one.